# Remove first part from url in tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have url in my page and I want to remove the front part (http://example.com/?) from href and keep only the first sub div and delete the rest div from the main div. I have to do this using js or jQuery how do I do it?

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/?https://someotherurl.org" target="_blank">google</a>
  <div class="div-1">
    data
  </div>

  <div>
    extra
  </div>
  <div>
    extra
  </div>

</div>

<!-- the final code I want is -->



<div class="main">
  <a href="https://someotherurl.org" target="_blank">google</a>
  <div class="div-1">
    data
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: is your `http://www.example.com/?` of fixed length?

Comment: What does your javascript look like?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code:

```js
var url=document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].childNodes[1].href;
url=url.split("?");
document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].childNodes[1].href=url[1];
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/?https://someotherurl.org"    target="_blank">google</a>
<div class="div-1">
</div>
</div>
```

I keep the chain to see how I select the element and the href attr.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to get the desired result, Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/uxqsxo1v/1/

```
var url = $('a').attr('href');
url = url.split('?');
var newUrl = url[1];
$('a').attr('href',newUrl);
```

Comment: my fault, i foagrgot to add '' in 'a' tag

Answer (score 0):

I prefer querySelector since it is more compatible than getElementsByClassName and can easily be converted to jQuery

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector('div.main>a'), 
      href = anchor.href.split("?")[1]; // assuming no other ? in the url
anchor.href=href;
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/?https://someotherurl.org" 
  target="_blank">google</a>
<div class="div-1"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
var $anchor=$("div.main>a");
$anchor.prop("href", $anchor.prop("href").split("?")[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/?https://someotherurl.org" target="_blank">google</a>
  <div class="div-1"></div>
</div>
```